# Does " - " mean stdout in bash?

Tags: bash

Is " - " a shortcut for stdout in bash? If not what does it mean? For example,

```
wget -q -O - $line
```

How about stdin?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As far as I know, `bash` isn't involved with the usage of dash. It's just a convention of many UNIX command line utilities to accept `-` as a placeholder for `stdin` or `stdout` when put in place of an input or output file name on the command line.

---

**Edit**: found it, this behavior is specified in the [POSIX Utility Syntax Guidelines, §12.2.13](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02) of *The Open Group Base Specifications*:

> For utilities that use operands to represent files to be opened for either reading or writing, the '-' operand should be used only to mean standard input (or standard output when it is clear from context that an output file is being specified).

Answer (score 10):

`-` is just a convention used by `wget` (and quite a few other tools) to indicate the output is to be sent to stdout. It's not part of bash, but it's a special case treated by the command itself (some commands will end up creating a "`-`" file if you assume this is the case). You could replace it with `/dev/stdout` (and you can generally use `/dev/stdin` as an input file when appropriate).

Answer (score 5):

`-` is not special in bash, it is simply given as a parameter to the program. Then it depends on the program how it interprets that `-`.

Commonly it denotes that stdin or stdout should be used, depending on context.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the program. Ususally, `-` means "send to the output".

Use `read`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "What's your name? "
read var1
echo "hello $var1"
```