# What does "-" mean in this linux command?

Tags: linux, cat

I am learning the cat command of linux, and I found this command :

```
$ echo 'Text through stdin' | cat - file.txt
```

What does "-" mean here? If I don't type it , then 'Text through stdin' will not be shown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does " - " mean stdout in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797795/does-mean-stdout-in-bash) (admittedly for stdin/stdout, depending on the context...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it is common to write `stdin` as dash (`-`).

even `man cat` mentions that:

> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

and the manpage even has an example illustrating the use of dash and ordinary filenames (which is quite close to your original question, but includes the answer):

```
   cat f - g
          Output f's contents, then standard input, then g's contents.
```

Comment: It is important to realise that after `stdin` has been read the file `file.txt` will then be displayed.

Comment: @PP. right, i added two more lines of the manpage (incidentally they come just after my original quote), that should make this explicit.

Answer (score 6):

`-` tells cat to read from `stdin`. This is quite common, a lot of apps read from stdin if you pass `-` to them.

Some apps use `-` as `stdout`.

Here is an example of downloading blender and instead of writing it to a file we write it directly to `stdout` and pipe it to tar, which expands it on the fly during download.

```
wget -c https://download.blender.org/source/blender-2.90.1.tar.xz -O - | tar -xzv
```

Here the `-O -` tells wget to write directly to `stdout`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo 'Text through stdin' | cat - file.txt
```

`-` tells `cat` to read from standard input, in this case, from the pipe, i.e, what `echo 'Text through stdin'` outputs.