# What does single dash after -D mean in curl command?

Tags: curl

What is the meaning of **-D -**? I only found out **-C -** in the curl docs.

```
curl -s -D - \
  -H "Referer:https://yahoo.com" \
  "https://something.com"
```

Comment: Dumps the headers to stdout. Pro tip: `man curl | grep -C 5 -- -D` (Grep the man page for `-D` and include 5 lines before and after.) `-` usually represents stdout. See for instance the `-o` option. "Specifying the output as '-' (a single dash) will force the output to be done to stdout."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does " - " mean stdout in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797795/does-mean-stdout-in-bash) (note that part of the answer was "no, this has nothing to do with bash").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the POSIX utility conventions document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html):

> **Guideline 13**: For utilities that use operands to represent files to be opened for either reading or writing, the '-' operand should be used to mean only standard input (or standard output when it is clear from context that an output file is being specified) or a file named -.

Thus, when `-` is used in a filename context, it is compliant with POSIX conventions to read or write the relevant data from stdin or stdout, as appropriate.