# What is the minus sign after "-o" for? (in curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash)

Tags: curl

I checked the curl documentation and it says -o option is for saving the downloaded data to a file. But i'm using the below command to install nvm and it has a minus sign after the o. What is it used for?
`curl -o-https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash`

If we are going to pipe the install.sh to bash, what's the use of saving it first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the magic of "-" (a dash) in command-line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045479/whats-the-magic-of-a-dash-in-command-line-parameters); or [Does `-` mean stdout in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797795/does-mean-stdout-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks! Yes I see that it was a duplicate. The original post answered my question.