# grep -f from start of line in target file

Tags: unix, grep

input.csv

```
12345,client1
2345,client1
345,client2
```

target.csv

```
12345,client1,2021-09-13
22345,client1,2021-09-14
44345,client2,2021-09-15
```

expected output

```
12345,client1,2021-09-13
```

tried grep -f but clearly its not the correct. is there any other option that I can add to search from start of line?

Comment: Take a look at `man grep` for a option to match only those lines containing whole words.

Answer (score 0):

If using ksh93, bash, zsh, or another shell that supports *process substitution*:

```sh
grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/' input.csv) target.csv
```

Adds a start of line anchor to each line of input.csv on the fly for `grep` to use.

Comment: `sed | grep -f-` will do the same in any shell.

Comment: @stevesliva I was wondering if someone would mention that. I didn't see anything in the POSIX description of `grep` about `-f -` reading from standard input so I didn't mention it as an alternative for people stuck on plain sh. Is that behavior standardized somewhere in the document?

Comment: Good question.  It's magic.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3797806/3120884 -- POSIX tools should not have '-' mean anything other than stdin or out in file context.  Not sure from the "shall" vs "should" discussion whether that means it's basically universal POSIX this century.